# How do I write a function that takes in a telephone number as a string and validates if it is a US phone number or not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

The function should return true if the passed string is a valid US phone number.

Comment: What kind of help do you need? It looks like you have a bunch of working inputs, from which a number of approaches could be taken: what specific problem are you having?

Comment: (Also note that sometimes people enter numbers like `888.555.1212` etc. so the separator character probably shouldn't be taken for granted.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how "valid" you want it to be.  if all you mean is that it contains exactly 10 digits, or 11 digits with the country code... then it's probably pretty simple.

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  var isValid = false;
  //only allow numbers, dashes, dots parentheses, and spaces
  if (/^[\d-()\s.]+$/ig.test(str)) {
    //replace all non-numbers with an empty string
    var justNumbers = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var count = justNumbers.length;
    if(count === 10 || (count === 11 && justNumbers[0] === "1") ){
      isValid = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(isValid, str);
  return isValid;
}

telephoneCheck("555-555-5555");   //true
telephoneCheck("1-555-555-5555"); //true
telephoneCheck("(555)5555555");   //true
telephoneCheck("(555) 555-5555"); //true
telephoneCheck("555 555 5555");   //true
telephoneCheck("5555555555");     //true
telephoneCheck("1 555 555 5555")  //true
telephoneCheck("2 555 555 5555")  //false (wrong country code)
telephoneCheck("800-692-7753");   //true
telephoneCheck("800.692.7753");   //true
telephoneCheck("692-7753");       //false (no area code)
telephoneCheck("");               //false (empty)
telephoneCheck("4");              //false (not enough digits)
telephoneCheck("8oo-six427676;laskdjf"); //false (just crazy)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has done all humanity a huge favor and published a phone number validation and formatting library: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

In your case, you can use the Javascript library available on NPM at https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber

```
npm install --save-prod google-libphonenumber
```

Then

```
// Get an instance of `PhoneNumberUtil`. 
const phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

// Result from isValidNumber().
console.log(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number));

// Result from isValidNumberForRegion().
console.log(phoneUtil.isValidNumberForRegion(number, 'US'));
```

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: The answer is: use Google's phone library. It's a reference to a library that solves the poster's problem.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289074/are-answers-with-only-links-to-libraries-okay

Comment: Updated with relevant content that would help the poster.

Answer (score 0):

The function should return true if the passed string is a valid US phone number.

OK. I know its project work for FreeCodeCamp javaScript challenge i would suggest reading and practicing more problems before attempting this challenge.
This can be solved just by regular expression no need to loop and all that.

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  let regEx = /^(1?\s?)(\d{3}|[(]\d{3}[)])[-\s]?(\d{3})[-\s]?(\d{4})$/;
  return regEx.test(str);
}
  
telephoneCheck("555-555-5555");
```

[Found this good article read here more about regular expressions](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/a-quick-and-simple-guide-to-javascript-regular-expressions/190263)